# кнопка submit JSP

Tags: java, html, веб-программирование, mvc, jsp

В JSP я заполнил форму и отправляю кнопкой на сервер для обработки.

```
<button formaction="/chat/${idTopic+1}" class="pull-right btn btn-primary" type="submit">Send</button>
```

Дело в том, что адрес генерируется автоматически, JSP одна на всех пользователей. 
Если просто submit то он отправляет на адрес /chat/ для обработки, а нужно на адрес /chat/1 ...или 2, 3 и тд. Это id конкретной станицы топика.

```
<button formaction="/chat/${idTopic+1}"
```

formaction делает из моей кнопки просто ссылку, в БД не сохраняется объект и меня перенаправляет на страницу.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "chat/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addMessage(@ModelAttribute("messageForm") Message messageForm, Model model){
    if(messageForm.getId() == null){
        messageForm.setTopicId (id);
        messageService.save (messageForm);
    }
    return "redirect:/chat/" + idURL;
}
```

тут по идее когда происходит отправка формы с "chat/{id}" программа обрабатывает POJO и сохраняет в БД, но этого не происходит. **submit отправляет на /chat/**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "chat/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String welcome(Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
    model.addAttribute ("messageForm", new Message ());
    //вытащим из URL id что-бы найти название топика в котором мы находимся
    String url = request.getRequestURI ();//URL текущая страница
    idURL = Integer.parseInt (url.split ("/chat/")[1]);//нужен для возвращения на ту же страницу POST
    id = idURL - 1; //А это нужно, что-бы в JSP мы знали, в каком именно топике находимся и какие отображать сообщения
    model.addAttribute ("idTopic", id);
    return "chat";
}
```

Ну а это GET, тут все стандартно. Если кто-то отправил по адресу "chat/{id}", то открыть стандартную для всех JSP с именем chat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Моя кошка очень умная, стоит ей объяснить проблему, стразу становится все ясно) (с) Александр Климов .. но это не точно.

Проблема в том, что в 
`@RequestMapping(value = "chat/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)` мы должны указывать не адрес с какой страницы исходит запрос, а с какой JSP он происходит.

Т.е. в моем случае, имя JSP "chat" и нужно указать `@RequestMapping(value = "chat", method = RequestMethod.POST)`

Так все работает!